# Why light comes from fire?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, physical-chemistry, combustion

We know that light is produced when a charge particle accelerates.

Fire doesn't have electric and magnetic field so how does light come from a fire?

Comment: Light is also caused by atomic state transitions

Comment: Pls give detailed but short answer

Comment: You have taken only one way that light can be generated and incorrectly assumed that is the *only* way. Check out some other ways, e.g., chemiluminescence and triboluminescence.

Answer (score 2):

Fire is really a *combustion reaction* in which a fuel is oxidided by air oxygen. The two so-called half reactions that take place are:

$$\text{Fu}\to \text{Fu}^{n+}+n \text{e}^-$$
$$\text{O}+2\text{e}^-\to \text{O}^{2-}$$

These *electron transfers* release energy, known as the *Gibbs Free Energy of Combustion*, in the form of heat energy.

This heat energy heats up the combustion gases and causes them to emit visible light (as well as IR radiation)

What exactly is the mechanism of radiation emission by the hot combustion gases [is explained in great detail here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/102280/how-is-the-light-from-a-fire-emitted).

.

Comment: How exactly does a heated gas emit photons?

Comment: Light is combination of electric and magnetic field , where are these fields in fire

Comment: @Ben: I've edited my post.

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari The emission of electromagnetic radiation by atoms/molecules does not require an explanation involving a *'combination of electric and magnetic field'*. Transitions of electrons inside said atoms/molecules from one to another energy level adequately explains the emission of EMR.

Answer (score 1):

Light is also produced by [atomic transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_electron_transition). This is when an electron leaves a higher (orbital) state and occupies a lower one. You can see it here:

[image: img1]

This is explained more extensively in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/102280/how-is-the-light-from-a-fire-emitted